# import com. ... cannot be resolved issue

Tags: import, solution

I found a carousel source code from internet.

Instead of importing project, I copied it to my project and pasted in the library files.

However, I still have  an error on the line:

```
import com.arduandro.CarouselView.R;
```

How can I fix it?

Problem occurs on the second line of the following code:

```
import com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper;

import com.arduandro.CarouselView.R;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Eclipse? If yes, you have to import the .jar and add it to the build path

Comment: No. I am using Android Studio